# PSTricks and color not useable together in Plain TeX?

Tags: color, pstricks, plain-tex, luapstricks

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\input luaotfload.sty
\input pstricks
\input pst-circ
\input color% destroys everything

\pspicture(-1, 0)(3.5, 4.5)
\circledipole[labeloffset = 0](0, 3)(3, 3){V}
\coil[dipolestyle=curved](0, 1)(3, 1){}
\wire(0, 1)(0, 3)
\wire(3, 1)(3, 3)
\endpspicture

\bye
```

When I compile this MWE with Plain LuaTeX, `\input color` destroys the `\pspicture`. When I load `color` before `pstricks`, then it crashes.

How to use both packages in Plain TeX? Why are they interfering?

Edit: Same result with Plain XeTeX.

Comment: You can't use xcolor and color at the same time.  OTOH, if xcolor is loaded, loading color is a giant leap backwards.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't use `xcolor`.

Comment: Apparently pstricks does.

Comment: Not in Plain TeX. Here, `\color{........}` leads to errors.

Comment: well with etex your example compiles if you undefine color before loading the package. With luatex something then still errors in luapstricks. Why are you using plain luatex instead of luaLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\input luaotfload.sty
%\input pstricks
\input pst-circ

\newrgbcolor{myCol}{0.2 0.5 0.8}

\pspicture(-1, 0)(3.5, 4.5)
\circledipole[labeloffset = 0](0, 3)(3, 3){V}
\coil[dipolestyle=curved](0, 1)(3, 1){}
\wire[linecolor=red](0, 1)(0, 3)
\wire(3, 1)(3, 3)
\endpspicture

{\red foo} {\myCol bar} baz
\bye
```

[image]

However, you cannot be sure that `luapstricks.lua` will always work with `luatex`. Using `lualatex` instead makes more sense.

Comment: OK, so what do I have to do, when I would like to use `pstricks` and `color` together? I need colored text as well as `pstricks`. (There are reasons for using Plain TeX instead of LaTeX.)

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: Thank you. So, `pstricks` adds color support for Plain TeX on its own. I did not know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that adds `xcolor` support to Plain TeX. The `color` package does something that destroys `PSTrticks` and I could not find the reason. But
`xcolor` works after some modifications.

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\catcode`\@=11

\csname pgfkeysloaded\endcsname% `pgfkeys` loads the Plain TeX color
                               % support by TikZ which does not
                               % even work here and is incompatible!

%\input pstricks
\input pst-circ

\suppressoutererror = 1% \outer
\input miniltx
\let\+\@undefined% defined by `plain.tex`
\def\XC@tgt@mod#1{#1}% to get package option `natural` (default)
\input xcolor.sty

\pspicture(-1, 0)(3.5, 4.5)
\circledipole[labeloffset = 0](0, 3)(3, 3){V}
\coil[dipolestyle=curved](0, 1)(3, 1){}
\wire[linecolor=blue](0, 1)(0, 3)
\wire(3, 1)(3, 3)
\endpspicture

\color{violet}

Test

\bye
```

Comment: do not expect that to continue to work. xcolor is a latex package and is not tested against miniltx. Any new version can contain changes that break in plain.